# FileNotFoundException: "Could not load file or assembly" although assembly exists

Tags: visual-studio, dependencies, ide, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I am trying to create a custom membership and role provider. The code for this seems to be fine, but when I try to go to the Security section of the Web Site Administration Tool, I get the following:

> The invoked member is not supported in
>   a dynamic assembly.

In reference to the first line of the first bit of NHibernate-related code that is called:

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
```

followed by:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load
>   file or assembly
>   'NHibernate.XmlSerializers,
>   Version=3.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

Before that I get a few:

> Culture name 'aspx' is not supported.

I have the providers in the App_Code folder and the NHibernate DLLs are copied to the Bin folder on execution of the application.

I am assuming it is to do with the providers not being able to find all of the relevant classes and dlls related to NHibernate and the Role class and so on.

---

For whatever reason, this problem went away.

Comment: I think this is a good question. There are times when it's useful to break on CLR exceptions, and the NHibernate.XmlSerializers exception is a distraction. The workaround is to generate a local copy of NHibernate.XmlSerializers.dll and put it in the same directory as NHibernate.dll. Instructions here: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/02/13/sgenexe-and-strongly-named-assemblies/. NHibernate.snk here: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate.snk. sgen.exe NHibernate.dll /type:NHibernate.Cfg.MappingSchema.HbmMapping /compiler:/keyfile:NHibernate.snk

Comment: as unlikely as it is, this question's answer just helped me.

Answer (score 37):

I had the same thing, turns out it wasn't really a problem. I had IDE set so that it will break on Exceptions

After reading this link below I realised.

http://www.mail-archive.com/nhusers@googlegroups.com/msg06043.html

You can simply hit F5 and continue running. That's pretty much all I know